# opscenter can't connect to agents after enabling ssl

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, datastax, opscenter

I'm setting up node-to-node encryption in AWS on ubuntu in a 3-node datastax enterprise 4.5.2 cluster. I followed these docs -

[1] -http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/sec/secNodeNodeEncryp.html 
[2] - http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/sec/secPrepareCerts.html
[3] - https://github.com/PatrickCallaghan/datastax-ssl-secure-cluster
[4] - http://datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/configure/opscEnableSSLpkg.html

1. I created the certs and the keystore. [1,2,3]
2. Added the certs to the truststore on each node [1,3]
3. edited cassandra.yaml to turn on node-to-node encryption (leaving client-to-node for another day) [1,3]
4. edited address.yaml to turn on encryption for datastax-agent [4]
5. restarted all nodes

'nodetool status' shows me all nodes are up normally. opscenter shows the nodes but gives the error message '0 of 3 agents are connected' What else needs to be done to allow opscenter to talk to the agents? Opsecenter is installed on one of the nodes, and it won't talk to the agent on the same box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opscenterd daemon failed to start correctly. examining /var/log/opscenter/opscenterd.log showed the following:

exceptions.ImportError: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

First, I tried the simple solution of linking 
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8 and
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libscrypto.so.0.9.8

but that didn't work. The solution was to install libssl0.9.8 on the server running opscenter
$ sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8

btw, this is opscenter 5.0.1.